# SVN Update - Most Simple Merge - After merge its still not happy

Tags: svn, merge

Trying to learn the basics of SVN (using SilkSVN command line for now).  I created a conflict, did "SVN Update" and selected Merge, then "(2) Use your version.  It says "merge of "Sample1.ps1" completed.  But then it puts the menu back on the screen and wants to to choose another option.  There was only one file in conflict.  Why didn't the update complete successfully after my merge?

c:\Code\Demo>svn commit -m "Test conflict"
Sending        Sample1.ps1
svn: E155011: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E155011: File 'C:\Code\Demo\Sample1.ps1' is out of date
svn: E160028: File '/Sample1.ps1' is out of date

```
c:\Code\Demo>svn update
Updating '.':
C    Sample1.ps1
Updated to revision 5.
Conflict discovered in file 'Sample1.ps1'.
Select: (p) postpone, (df) show diff, (e) edit file, (m) merge,
        (mc) my side of conflict, (tc) their side of conflict,
        (s) show all options: m
Merging 'Sample1.ps1'.
Conflicting section found during merge:
(1) their version (at line 6)         |(2) your version (at line 6)
--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------
Write-Host "The Demo2 Change End"     |Write-Host "The End - Some other Demo
--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------
Select: (1) use their version, (2) use your version,
        (12) their version first, then yours,
        (21) your version first, then theirs,
        (e1) edit their version and use the result,
        (e2) edit your version and use the result,
        (eb) edit both versions and use the result,
        (p) postpone this conflicting section leaving conflict markers,
        (a) abort file merge and return to main menu: 2
Merge of 'Sample1.ps1' completed.
Select: (p) postpone, (df) show diff, (e) edit file, (m) merge,
        (r) mark resolved, (mc) my side of conflict,
        (tc) their side of conflict, (s) show all options: s
```

Comment: With a `svn up`, I usually end up selecting `postpone` and resolving the issue manually by myself. Then, using `svn resolved` to mark the file resolved. I don't like trying to resolve in the middle of an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply need to pick the "R" for "Resolved".  I thought the merge resolved it, not sure why the final step is required.